# can we use something better than more for tab completion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

`more` is not as convenient as `less`.

Is it possible to use something better than `more` for tab completion, when `ls` and then tab? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is shell dependent. I use the Fish shell which has better autocompletion. Zsh is supposed to have this as well, you just have to enable it first (somehow).

Comment: I think switching to zsh or fish is the answer. Bash isn't as sophisticated.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks. Will consider zsh some time.

Comment: I don't think `bash` actually uses the *program* `more` for tab completion, but internal paging code.

Comment: @Tim: Zsh needs a bunch of configuring before you get anything, that is my experience. Fish will be nice right out of the box.

Comment: not sure what "bash isn't as sophisticated" means. maybe it's the name that seems garish. Nonetheless, 'bash' does not use 'more' for tab completion. And regarding paging through "ls" output, you may have "ls" aliased to "ls | more"? => try: `$ type ls` => see if you're doing more than just listing files. Tab completion in bash can be customized, using the `complete` command.

Comment: zsh used to have better tab completion than bash.  These days, bash has caught up, though you may have to install an extra package ([`bash-completion`](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/)) and/or source an extra file (e.g. `source /etc/bash_completion`).  IMHO, zsh's completion is still better, but this makes bash much much closer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257724/set-less-as-pager-in-psql

Answer (score 7):

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2014-03/msg00018.html

> Readline does not use `more', or any other external program; it uses its
>   own internal pager.  There is no user-configurable hook to change that.

Looks like you're out of luck.